# How to Get ContentControl Children Within Template

Tags: c#, wpf

I spent several hours searching and testing and can't get it to work. I want to have a UserControl that exposes a template to fill a section of the UserControl. I got it to work by creating a DependencyProperty of type ContentTemplate (or DataTemplate?). Then I display it like this

```
<ContentControl x:Name="PlayerContent" ContentTemplate="{Binding PlayerTemplate, ElementName=W}" />
```

Now the problem is that when I use the UserControl I cannot set element names within the template.

```
<local:MediaPlayerWpf x:Name="PlayerUI" Height="auto" Width="auto">
    <local:MediaPlayerWpf.PlayerTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="Host" Focusable="False" />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </local:MediaPlayerWpf.PlayerTemplate>
</local:MediaPlayerWpf>
```

This throws

> Cannot set Name attribute value 'Host' on element
>   'WindowsFormsHost'. 'WindowsFormsHost' is under the
>   scope of element 'MediaPlayerWpf', which already had a name registered
>   when it was defined in another scope.

As a result, I have no way of accessing the control defined within the template. I also found no way of accessing the root of the children displayed in the ContentControl.

How can I access the "Host" control defined in the template?

Comment: Access from where? Please post the code that shows what you're trying to do. The solution depends on that.

Comment: I have came across the same issue several times. Don't remember the exact reason, but I'm sure that if you inherit from Control instead of UserControl  you won't get this error.

Comment: I want to access it from the window declaring the template content. There's no other code yet, the UI fails to compile at x:Name="Host". If I change UserControl to Control, then I can't define the content of my control. Alternatively, I could take the type of a class and create an instance of that class to place in the container instead of using a template, perhaps? Problem is the designer doesn't allow setting a property to a Type, so it would have to be done in the code-behind. Or perhaps just a SetContent() method where I pass the content object.

Comment: I've seen it before and am reading it again: "User Controls do not support complex customization, control templates, and difficult to style."

Answer (score 0):

It seems we can't use templates in such a way within UserControl. I don't know whether there's a work-around.

I ended up taking a different approach. I exposed a property to set the content.

```
public static DependencyProperty HostProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Host", typeof(PlayerBase), typeof(MediaPlayerWpf), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnHostChanged));
public PlayerBase Host { get => (PlayerBase)base.GetValue(HostProperty); set => base.SetValue(HostProperty, value); }
private static void OnHostChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    MediaPlayerWpf P = d as MediaPlayerWpf;
    if (e.OldValue != null)
        P.HostGrid.Children.Remove(e.OldValue as PlayerBase);
    if (e.NewValue != null) {
        P.HostGrid.Children.Add(e.NewValue as PlayerBase);
        P.UI.PlayerHost = e.NewValue as PlayerBase;
    }
}
```

Then in the code-behind where the class is being used, I set it like this

```
Player.Host = new MpvMediaPlayerHost();
```

At least it's working.

EDIT: A better solution is to switch from User Control to Custom Control. I still applied the solution above, and switching to Custom Control allowed me to set the Host in a derived class' constructor.